# sqlalchamy update one to many relation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am writing simple falsk application and using flask_marshmallow.

I have following code

```
class AuthorSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Author

class BookSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Book

db.create_all()

#  Scenario 1: insert new author and new book
data = {'books': [{"title":"xyz"}], 'name': 'Chuck Paluhniuk'}
aschema = AuthorSchema().load(data).data
aschema.firstbook = aschema.books[0].title
db.session.add(aschema)
db.session.commit()

# Scenario 2:  update existing author and insert new book
updated =  {'books': [{"title":"cat"}], 'name': 'Chuck Paluhniuk'}
aschema = AuthorSchema().load(updated).data
author = db.session.query(Author).filter_by(name=aschema.name).first()
author.firstbook =  aschema.books[0].title
author.books.append(aschema.books[0])
db.session.commit()
```

I am using sqllite. I have two scenario as mentioned in the above code.  When i run the above code,

Expected recult is,

```
1 record in author table (first book = cat, after update) 
2 records in book table.
```

But **i am seeing 2 records in author table**. one with empty firstbook.  What went wrong in the above code?[image]

Comment: Not having done anything with flask_marshmallow and the ilk, I'd guess `aschema = AuthorSchema().load(updated).data` creates an `Author` and its related `Book`s, based on the given data. Now when you do `author.books.append(aschema.books[0])` you add the book object *and its related objects* to the current session, which includes the "dummy" `Author`. So when you commit, the extra author is also added to the DB.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, How can i avoid this ? can you please help me

Comment: Again guessing, but either include primary keys for existing instances in the data that you load (`id` for Author), or [pass `instance` argument to `load()`](http://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#marshmallow_sqlalchemy.ModelSchema.load). That might do or might not do what you're after.